# Yup.mixed().test() not working with Formik in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, formik, yup

I have created a form and taking some inputs like studentName, photo etc. And I want to validate these inputs. For this I am using Formik & Yup.

1. studentName:- At least 3 characters, Only A-Za-z characters allowed
2. photo:- file should not greater than 1mb, only jpeg & png file types are allowed

> Validation for studentName works fine but doesn't work for photo. When I try to upload file then always it is giving error as **Uploaded file is too big** even though I am uploading greater than 1mb. In simple words the following condition is not working.

```
photo: Yup.mixed()
  .test('FILE_SIZE', 'Uploaded file is too big.', (value) => !value || (value && value.size >= FILE_SIZE))
  .test(
    'FILE_FORMAT',
    'Uploaded file has unsupported format.',
    (value) => !value || (value && SUPPORTED_FORMATS.includes(value.type))
  )
```

Sanbox URL: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-mountain-gol1l

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { ErrorMessage, Field, Form, Formik } from "formik";
import React from "react";
import * as Yup from "yup";

export default function App() {
  const FILE_SIZE = 1000000; //1mb
  const SUPPORTED_FORMATS = [
    "image/jpg",
    "image/jpeg",
    "image/png"
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Formik
        initialValues={{
          studentName: "",
          photo: null
        }}
        validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
          studentName: Yup.string()
            .min(3, "Name cannot be less than 3 characters")
            .matches(/^[A-Za-z ]*$/, "Please enter valid name")
            .required("Student Name is required"),
          photo: Yup.mixed()
            .required("A file is required")
            .test(
              "FILE_SIZE",
              "Uploaded file is too big.",
              (value) => !value || (value && value.size >= FILE_SIZE)
            )
            .test(
              "FILE_FORMAT",
              "Uploaded file has unsupported format.",
              (value) =>
                !value || (value && SUPPORTED_FORMATS.includes(value.type))
            )
        })}
        render={({ errors, touched }) => (
          <Form>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label className="col-sm-4 control-label">Student Name</label>
              <div className="col-sm-8">
                <Field
                  id="studentName"
                  name="studentName"
                  type="text"
                  className={
                    "form-control" +
                    (errors.studentName && touched.studentName
                      ? " is-invalid"
                      : "")
                  }
                />
                <ErrorMessage
                  name="studentName"
                  component="div"
                  className="invalid-feedback"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label className="col-sm-4 control-label">Photo</label>
              <div className="col-sm-8">
                <Field
                  id="photo"
                  name="photo"
                  type="file"
                  className={
                    "form-control" +
                    (errors.photo && touched.photo ? " is-invalid" : "")
                  }
                />
                <ErrorMessage
                  name="photo"
                  component="div"
                  className="invalid-feedback"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </Form>
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have fixed this already, but to me it seems that the issue is with this line

```
(value) => !value || (value && value.size >= FILE_SIZE)
```

This should return true if value.size is smaller than FILE_SIZE (not greater like in your code).